# Hard xquery to implement

Tags: xml, xquery

i'm currently studing xQuery language, while i was doing some exercises i've found a query that i'm not able to do. I really wish you can help me.

I have n sorted files that have the same nodes but different values inside the "value" attribute, like that one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <source name="File1.txt">
        <line nr="1" value="13" />
        <line nr="2" value="10" />
        <line nr="3" value="5" />
    </source>
    <source name="File2.txt">
        <line nr="1" value="2" />
    </source>
</root>
```

I have to write an xquery that takes all the source tags and for each source tag it will delete the lines where the value attribute is less than 10.

In this case, the result would have been:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <source name="File1.txt">
            <line nr="1" value="13" />
            <line nr="2" value="10" />
        </source>
        <source name="File2.txt" />
    </root>
```

So, for each xml file i will generate a new file, like the one above, that i'm gonna call "B".

Now, i have to create a query that will create a new unique xml file (i'm gonna call it C) that will contains the following: given that each B file have a prioritization (es: B12 > B10 > B8 > ... ), i have to open in order the B files and:

1. If a source node is missing in C, copy it inside.
2. For each line node, add a new attribute called "pos" that will represent the position, inside the B files prioritization, of the first B file that contains that line, inside that source node.

Like the given example:
Prioritization: B3, B1, B2, B4.

- Open B3, for each source node, copy it inside the C file (It's the first one, so it will just copy them)

  - For each line node inside that source node, copy all the lines (It's the first one, so i will just copy them) and add the attribute "pos" with value 1 (position of B3 inside the prioritization) for each line.
- Open B1, for each source node, if this is missing inside the C file, copy it inside the C file.

  - For each line node inside that source node, copy all the lines that are missing and add the attribute "pos" with value 2.
- Open B2, for each source node, if this is missing inside the C file, copy it inside the C file.

  - For each line node inside that source node, copy all the lines that are missing and add the attribute "pos" with value 3.
- Open B4, for each source node, if this is missing inside the C file, copy it inside the C file.

  - For each line node inside that source node, copy all the lines that are missing and add the attribute "pos" with value 4.

This is it, i know it's not easy (i think), so i really want to understand how to script a query that realize all the intructions above.

Thank you very, very, much for who's gonna help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of query where the output has only minor changes from the input is actually much easier to do using XSLT. Furthermore, XSLT is capable of producing multiple output files during a single execution, which is not directly possible in XQuery. In XSLT 3.0 this might be:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="line[@value lt 10]"/>

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection('file:///input-dir')">
    <xsl:result-document href="{tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

To do this in XQuery, it's probably best to execute the query once per input file which means you need logic in some external language to iterate of the input files and set the corresponding output file for each input. You then need a recursive function which takes any element and if it isn't one of the elements you want to delete, creates a new element with the same name, copies the attributes, and calls itself to process the children. So it can be done, but it's a lot more work.